# Yii how to validate one part of fields and than the whole form?

Tags: php, forms, validation, yii

I have few fields in my form, and all of them are required. One of those field is fileField. So what I am trying to do is using Transaction validate one part of fields, and if everything is ok for those fields, upload image, save on disk, set another field's values and save all fields in database.

But as I wrote the problem is that all fields need to be set. And when I will validate one part of parameters, another will not be set, so validation will return "false".

**P.S.**
Sorry for my English skills

Comment: Can you add your code along with model rules, controller and fields to validate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some ways to do that.

First, You can create a validation class.
for example:

```
class testModel extends CModel{
    public $test;
    public function attributeNames() {
        return array(
            'test'=>'Test'
        );
    }
    public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('test','required'),
                array('test','exist','className'=>'testClass','attributeName'=>'testAtttibute')
        );
    }
}
```

Then

```
$test=new testModel();
$test->test=$_POST['ANYNAME'];
if($test->validate()){
    //Do something
}
```

You can also validate only one attribute by passing your attribute into validate method

```
$test->validate(array('test','other attr');
```